# Re-run response function from jQuery $.post() method till response equals value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, response

I am using a `$.post` method to send some data. In the post response function I want to be able to keep re-running the post response function till the `data.val` inside `function(data, status)` comes back as 'DONE'.

Right now once the post is done, the `data.val` is set to `started`. How do I keep checking till the value of `data.val` till it becomes `DONE`.

This is what I have for now: This is for each value inside array a post call is done

```
arr.forEach(d=>{
$.post(post_call, JSON.stringify(json_string),
    function(data, status) {
        if (data.val == 'started') {
           //re run function
        }
        else {
          //do something
        }
   }, 'json');
});
```

I am not very sure about how to go about that.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Do you want to execute the POST request again with the same parameters until the response matches what you're after (ie _polling_)?

Comment: @Phil, Yes, thats what I want to do